# Spring Exception handler - Handling multiple exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Below is my ExceptionHandler method to handle different exceptions that can be thrown from service class.

```
@ExceptionHandler({ExceptionA.class, ExceptionB.class, ExceptionC.class})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
public void handle(ExceptionA e) {
    log.error("Exception occurred: {} {}", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

When ExceptionA is thrown, everything works as expected. But when ExceptionB is thrown, it gives the error `No suitable resolver for argument 0 of type 'ExceptionA'`. I guess its because the method argument for handle method is Exception A (still I would expect the error message should say `No resolver for Exception B`).

What should be the method argument for handle method so that it can handle any of the 3 exceptions?

Note: All Exceptions are created by extending from RuntimeException.

Answer (score 3):

You need a common base class as parameter type, e.g RuntimeException:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ExceptionA.class, ExceptionB.class, ExceptionC.class})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
public void handle(RuntimeException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Comment: Now this method handles every exception that extends RuntimeException. I want this method to handle only one of these 3 exceptions

Comment: @KumarV No, it doesn't. This method only handles the exceptions defined in `@ExceptionHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own base class extending RuntimeException

```
public class HandledRuntimeException extends RuntimeException{
}
```

and extend this class from your exception class like,

```
public class ExceptionA extends HandledRuntimeException{
}
```

and finally, in your handle method, you can change as below

```
@ExceptionHandler({HandledRuntimeException.class})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
public void handle(HandledRuntimeException e) {
    log.error("Exception occurred: {} {}", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```